# Type synonyms in java

Tags: java, scala, types

Is there anyway (a workaround) to define type synonyms in Java, similar to the following definition in Scala?

```
type Row = List[Int];
```

---

Though it might not be exactly the same, I was thinking of the following code (I replaced List with ArrayList, since List is an interface in Java):

```
public class Row extends ArrayList<Integer>{}
```

Is there any other way to achieve type synonym mechanism in java?

Comment: I don't think so.  The `extends` is the best you can do.  Since `List<Integer>` (not `List<Int>`) is an interface, I think that what you wrote may be good enough, but I'm not sure.  If you do this with a _concrete_ type, then to get a type that is as close as possible to being equivalent, you also have to redeclare all the constructors and make them all just `super(arguments);`.

Comment: Nope, there is no way. Your method is considered in some circles to be an anti-pattern.

Comment: @ajb I changed List to ArrayList. You are right, List is interface in java.

Comment: "Considered in some circles to be an anti-pattern"...  personally, I'd want to see concrete reasons why.  In general, though, a class should represent a cohesive concept; creating a class just to rename a type isn't usually the best use, IMHO.  And if the class represents a concept, the `ArrayList<Integer>` would be considered the implementation of that concept, and therefore should be a private field instead of a superclass.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have a very complex type like `ArrayList<Map<String,Future<Map<String,List<CustomerData>>>>>`, maybe a type rename would enhance readability; I've seen this sort of type in practice, and spelling out the entire `ArrayList` type name multiple times really clutters the code.  (But thinking of the concept it represents, and coming up with a new class that represents this concept, would be better.)

Comment: Also, there are cases in Java where using arrays and generics together are restricted, and you could use `Row` in a context where using `List<Integer>` would be an error.  That would be a legitimate reason for the type rename, I think.

Comment: I think my design is going to end up having something like `ArrayList<Map<String,Future<Map<String,List<CustomerData>>>>>`, so I am thinking to switch to Scala! if I can not find an easy workaround.

Comment: I'd suggest to try with a better delegation / composition. I'd rather not pile up stuff within collections that way...
Map<String, List<CustomerData> -> CustomerDataMap;
Map<String, Future<CustomerData> -> FutureMap.
You end up with a List<FutureMap> ...

Comment: as medveshonok117 said, better composition will give you a clear result than simply throwing every nested generic altogether.
And yes. ```extends``` is the only way to it right in Java.

Comment: I would also suggest to take a look at TypeLiteral, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655921/use-of-typeliteral-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. See [Is there a Java equivalent or methodology for the typedef keyword in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195206/is-there-a-java-equivalent-or-methodology-for-the-typedef-keyword-in-c) for an older duplicate of this question, using C++ terminology instead of Scala terminology.