# The java "Object" Class equivalent in Scala

Tags: java, scala, types

It seems for a [good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563605/type-synonyms-in-java?noredirect=1#comment49198703_30563605) I need to switch to Scala! So, excuse me if my question might seem novice.

It seems that **Any** in scala is the [supper class of all types](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128) and might be considered as an **Object** type equivalent  in Java. But type **Any** is abstract, while **Object** is not. More concretely, I can not write the following code in scala (since class Any is abstract and cannot be instantiated):

```
val k:Any = new Any();
```

while I can write the following code in Java:

```
Object k=new Object();
```

What should I use if I need a concrete equivalent type of java Object type?

Comment: Why would you need to instantiate an Object in a Scala program? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Maybe he failed to write `new MyTrait` and now wants to write something like `new AnyRef with MyTrait` instead of `new MyTrait{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**AnyRef** type which is not abstract seems to be the equivalent of the Java **Object Class** (see [this](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/))

so the following works in scala:

```
  val k:AnyRef = new AnyRef();
```

Comment: Not useful.But *does* answer the OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

`AnyRef` is the equivalent of java's `Object`. (Scala unifies the type system rather than having the object/primitive distinction that Java has. So an instance of `Any` might be a descendant of `Object`/`AnyRef`, or an instance of a Java primitive type (e.g. `int`). (Or it could also be a "value class" descending from `AnyVal`)).